# How to abort a Firestore transaction in case of error

Tags: firebase, promise, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore `runTransaction` method in a https Cloud function (running Express).
What I want is ensure that if any of the read or write fails the other transaction reads or writes won't run or will rollback if needed.

**Transaction**

```
admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
  const { uid, artworkUid, tagLabel } = req.body;

  if (!tagLabel) {
    return Promise.reject('Missing parameters: "tagLabel"');
  }

  if (!artworkUid) {
    return Promise.reject('Missing parameters: "artworkUid"');
  }

  if (tagLabel.length < 3) {
    return Promise.reject('The tag must be at least 3 characters long');
  }

  const [ user, artwork ] = await Promise.all([
    getUser(uid),
    getArtwork(artworkUid)
  ]);

  return Promise.all([
    addArtworkTag({
      artwork,
      tagLabel,
      proposer: user
    }, t),
    giveXpFor({
      user,
      action: 'add-artwork-tags',
      type: user.can('add-artwork-tags') ? 'effective' : 'temporary'
    }, t)
  ])
})
.catch(err => res.status(403).send(err))
.then(() => res.status(200).send());
```

As you can see the `addArtworkTag` and `giveXpFor` functions take the `t` in parameter.

**addArtworkTag**

```
export const addArtworkTag = function(params: { artwork: any, tagLabel: string, proposer: ShadraUser }, t?: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction): Promise<any> {
  const { artwork, tagLabel, proposer } = params;

  if (!artwork || !proposer || typeof tagLabel !== 'string') {
    return Promise.reject('Can\'t add the tag. Bad/missing datas');
  }

  const tag = <any>{
    slug: slugify(tagLabel),
    label: tagLabel,
    status: proposer.can('add-artwork-tags') ? 'validated' : 'proposed',
    proposerUid: proposer.uid
  };

  const tags = artwork.tags || [];
  tags.push(tag);

  const artworkRef = admin.firestore().doc(`artworks/${artwork.uid}`);

  t.set(artworkRef, { tags }, { merge: true });
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

My question is: If the `addArtworkTag` function fails (because of a bad parameter for instance) how can I abort (or even rollback) the transaction so `giveXpFor` is not called

Thanks a lot

PS: I think I've misused transactions... What I should do is probably just use sequential promises instead of Promise.all, right ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [API documentation for runTransaction](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Firestore#runTransaction) states:

> If the transaction completed successfully or was explicitly aborted
>   (by the updateFunction returning a failed Promise), the Promise
>   returned by the updateFunction will be returned here. Else if the
>   transaction failed, a rejected Promise with the corresponding failure
>   error will be returned.

All you have to do the fail a transaction correctly is return a rejected promise.  It doesn't matter what you've done in that transaction - all of it will be rolled back.

Comment: That's it. Thanks

Comment: Link seems to be dead.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about `runTransaction` To make your functions and queries more stable you should be using the following multiple times to stop your entire script from crashing.

```
try {
 //some code
} catch (e) {

 //put code here to flag up issues with runTransaction

 console.error("Oh No, Not Again said the PlantPot", e);
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data