# Flutter Cloud Firestore Plugin: How reject a transaction?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a transaction using cloud_firestore plugin and I want to reject a transaction if a particular field of data does not match a condition

```
final refProdotti = refs.getSubReferences('products');
final refOrdini = refs.getSubReferences('orders');

return refs.db.runTransaction((trans) async {

  for(var productOrder in order.prodotti) {
    var refProdotto = refProdotti.document(productOrder.prodottoId);
    print(productOrder.prodottoId);
    var docProdotto = await trans.get(refProdotto);

    var oldQuantita = docProdotto.data['quantity'];

    if(oldQuantita < productOrder.quantita){

      throw docProdotto.data['nome'] + ' not available';
    }

    //aggiorno la quantità nella collezione prodotto
    var newQuantita = oldQuantita - productOrder.quantita;
    await trans.update(refProdotto, { 'quantity': newQuantita });
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I throw an Exception I get an PlatformException(Every document read in a transaction must also be written in that transaction., null).

I tried to use Future.error(..) instead throwing an exception, but using that the transaction is done without error.

What is the way to stop a transaction?

Comment: A transaction handler returns a `Future<dynamic>`. If that Future is rejected, the transaction is aborted. So returning `Future.error` from your transaction handler is the right solution. Also see Doug's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986647 Why do you expect that to then return an error up though?

Comment: any luck with this? I am not able to reject a transaction from flutter.
throwing exceptions or returning flutter.error don't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but you can try throwing a FirebaseException to terminate the transaction.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

...


try {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  await firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {
     ...
     throw FirebaseException(plugin: 'cloud_firestore', code: 'predefined-condition-failed');
     ...
  });
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
   if (e.code == 'predefined-condition-failed') {
     // Do something
   }
   ...
}
...
```